Exception class eexternalException with message.... ERROR
I am running a Borland c++ builder 6 IDE. We have a system on an old XP that works fine. But when I install the Borland c++ builder 6 onto a windows 10 machine or for that matter a different XP machine. It builds with no errors but when I try to run it is gives me:
"Project {project name] raised exception class EExternalException with message 'External exception C0FB007E'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue."
It blows up when it tries to call a function in one of the DLL programs. It doesn't seem to recognize the DLL. If I put a break point in it I get the Green line with the circle with an X. To me that indicate it can't be reached. I have every program the same as the working computer and all the configuration set identical but it still doesn't seem to work. I don't see why since the dll's and the programs are all built with the same IDE. Can anyone give me a hint on where/what to look for to solve this.
Thanks in Advance.
Scott
I tried rebuild every DLL. The couple of packages that we include. Various config setting.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
